# Android unhandled exception

Tags: java, android, exception, rx-java

I want to implement a global handler to catch all possible exception that are not catch in the application.

We use a Rx in our project. I found this global handler:

```
RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerErrorHandler(new RxJavaErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable e) {
        super.handleError(e);
    }
});
```

however, there is also this handler:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

    }
});
```

which states in its documentation: 
"Sets the default uncaught exception handler. This handler is invoked in case any Thread dies due to an unhandled exception"

Does placing "Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler" in the 'Application' class (main entry point) catch exceptions in the Rx methods also?

Comment: Use `Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two separate utilities that are only tangentially related.

The `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is for any `Exception` percolated up through the system that isn't caught. Uncaught exceptions are what crashes your app, so people often use the default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for crash tracking.

The `RxJavaErrorHandler` is just for RxJava logging purposes. *Every* time `onError` is called for *any* subscription, it calls this method. It calls it whether there's already `onError` handling or not, nor should you use it for any sort of flow control, so it's really only useful for logging.

It sounds like what you want is to use the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. It will catch anything that the app didn't handle itself (including RxJava).

Comment: BTW, if your goal is to mask exceptions to prevent crashes, then I would strongly warn against it. This can leave your app in an unusable state. Sure, it didn't crash, but now it's in a weird state it should never be in. IMO, it's better to just crash and then debug the crash later.